# Parallel search in 2 collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, plinq

So, I have 2 collection (the first - all symbols and the second - searching)

```
IEnumerable<MarketSymbol> metadata; // 1
string [] symbols;                  // 2
```

For example,
`class MarketSymbol { string MarketSymbol {get;set;} }`

And I want to find all the same `symbols` in `metadata` by property `MarketSymbol{get;set;}`.

But I'll need to find all symbols trevalling through `metadata` only 1 time.

#### Result must be

return `MarketSymbol[]` || `IEnumerable<MarketSymbol> ...` || `add result to List<MarketSymbol> ...`

Suggestion: using **PLINQ**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** Added Stopwatch so You can see if it is really worth to use parallel depending on your list size.

```
IEnumerable<MarketSymbol> metadata = new List<MarketSymbol> {
                        new MarketSymbol{  _MarketSymbol = "test3"  },
                        new MarketSymbol{ _MarketSymbol = "test2" }
                    };
            string[] symbols = new string[] { "test", "test2", "test3" };
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();
            var list = metadata.Where(x => symbols.Contains(x._MarketSymbol)).AsEnumerable().ToList();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);

            stopwatch.Start();
            var list2 = symbols.Intersect(metadata.Select(x => x._MarketSymbol)).ToList();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);

            stopwatch.Start();
            var list3 = symbols.AsParallel().Intersect(metadata.Select(x => x._MarketSymbol).AsParallel()).ToList();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Result list, list2 and list3: test3, test2

Comment: Hello, Thanks for you help :) Maybe, Do you know as it decide with using parallel PLINQ method?

Comment: List3 I think is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. put the symbols array in an HashSet
2. Create a new result collection which will contain the results
3. start traversing the metadata collection, if the current item is contained in the HashSet, add it to the result collection.

In this way you will traverse the metadata only once.